# how to remove this warning "Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file."

Tags: android, firebase

[module gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6QY6.png) [project gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdYTB.png)Here is the code snippet of module Gradle file where I added the "`com.google.gms.google-services`" at the bottom of the build Gradle file. I am still seeing the warning "Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.". How can I remove the warning?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':app')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Why do you have the two dependencies in the same file?

Comment: I made a dynamic module. So, I put all firebase dependency in the same build file( module).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve this, you should add the following line of code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Inside the `build.gradle` file (Module: app) and **not** in the build.gradle file (Project). So to solve this, just change the location of the above line of code.

Comment: If I change the location, I got the error: "Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found." All of my firebase dependency in module builde gradle file.

Comment: In this case, add the `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` in the build.gradle file (Project), right after `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`. Does it work now?

Comment: I made a dynamic module. So, I put all firebase dependency in the same build file( module). If I add the "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'" in the build.gradle(project) , it will make the dependency on the base project.

Comment: Please add to your question how you files (both) look like now after the changes.

Comment: I uploaded two build file images

Comment: No, it's not correct. As I mentioned in an above comment, **move** `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'` from the file in which exist now, in the other file between `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'` dependecy and Kotlin dependency. Does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

Now it has changed to:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

in the build.gradle (Module)

Answer (score 1):

Just what the error message says 'Please apply google-services plugin at the *bottom* of the *build file*'

Before this line used to the the top of the page in build.gradle (App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...
```

Now delete that and move it to the bottom of the page, like this

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Seems like things have changed in the latest version of the Android. This will get rid of the error. The accepted answer did not work for me, may be got older.